# CSVLoader--Error, not in CLASSPATH?

Tags: java, csv, ide, classpath, weka

I write a program in java using weka to classify my data.

The first version uses ArffLoader to load .Arff files and that version can run without any problem.

However, when I change my code to uses CSVLoader, I run into a following error:

```
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
```

I have already change the target file to .CSV files and imported:

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;
```

Can someone tell me what's the problem? The only thing I changed is from using ArffLoader, I tried to use CSVLoader instead.

Ps. Please excuse my poor English.

Comment: I set wrong class index in CSV....

    instances.setClassIndex(instances.numAttributes() - 1);

Which is equal to 27.
The index for my .CSV file should be 3 instead of that.
Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

seems like your `jdbc driver` is not included in the `classpath`.. pls cross check it..!!!

Comment: How can I add classpath to my project?
It's not in Windows environment variables right?

Comment: Never mind that--it was problem on my part. I set wrong index for class in CSV.... that it why I don't get any result. Sorry.